# Change the color of specific labels in sns.heatmap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

Is there a way to change the color of specific labels in sns.heatmap?

Basing my attempt [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292737/change-the-color-for-ytick-labels-in-seaborn-clustermap), I tried the following:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(cor, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
g = sns.heatmap(cor,
            vmin=-1,
            cmap='coolwarm',
            annot=False,
            mask = mask);

columns = df.columns
lut = dict(zip(columns, "rbg"))
row_colors = columns.map(lut)

for tick_label in g.ax_heatmap.axes.get_yticklabels():
    tick_text = tick_label.get_text()
    if tick_text == 'ascii':
        column = columns.loc[int(tick_text)]
        tick_label.set_color(lut[column])
```

But got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-204-67642fc463ec> in <module>
     12 row_colors = columns.map(lut)
     13 
---> 14 for tick_label in g.ax_heatmap.axes.get_yticklabels():
     15     tick_text = tick_label.get_text()
     16     if tick_text == 'ascii':

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'ax_heatmap'
```

And a heatmap where the `ascii` label is not red.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you copied was for a `clustermap`, which returns an object with several axes.

Here, you are using `heatmap` which operates on a single axes. You should write:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(cor,
            vmin=-1,
            cmap='coolwarm',
            annot=False,
            mask = mask);
(...)
for tick_label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    (...)
```